# Is there a way to revoke an active session on GitLab?

Tags: session, gitlab

Is there a way to revoke an active session on GitLab? I tried to revoke an active session on the active session settings but there is no button to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is pending, as a feature request in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 59408](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/59408) and [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 27518](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/27518)

> This feature existed before, but was removed due to reasons listed [in the linked issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/59408#note_194694296).

It was a security issue about "a way for any logged in user (attacker) to escalate his privileges to gitlab administrator if the real gitlab administrator impersonates attacker's account."

So:

> to delete a single session you would need the session_id which is no longer exposed in the UI. As a workaround, you can delete all sessions of the user from Rails console:

```
ActiveSession.list(user).each{ |session| ActiveSession.destroy(user, session.session_id)}
```

The [Merge Request 17462](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/merge_requests/17462) is in progress.

Comment: Is there a way to log everyone out (revoke all sessions of all users)?

Comment: @HelloWorld Not that I know of (and I don't see much in https://gitlab.com/search?group_id=9970&project_id=278964&repository_ref=master&scope=issues&search=revoke+all+active+sessions&snippets=false). This is more user by user, for a user to revoke all active sessions (his/her own sessions)